# How to let <t:inputCalendar> retain time part during submit

Tags: jsf, datetime, calendar, tomahawk

In my JSP page I added new date component to an existing field, where by previously this field is a backend field and its value is updated automatically by system.

```
 <t:inputCalendar id="Tab4DateReceived" monthYearRowClass="yearMonthHeader" weekRowClass="weekHeader"  
   currentDayCellClass="currentDayCell" value="#{Str.reportedDate}" renderAsPopup="true"  
   popupTodayString="#{msgs.popup_today_string}" popupWeekString="#{msgs.popup_week_string}"
   size="9" maxlength="10" renderPopupButtonAsImage="true" popupDateFormat="#{FacesUtils.datePattern}" onblur="validateDate(this)" tabindex="408">
     <f:validator validatorId="CurrentDateValidator"/>
 </t:inputCalendar>
```

Originally this field value has date and time, but when the record is updated without changing its value, the time becomes 00:00:00 and date remain the same.
For example:

```
Original: 31/12/2009 17:32:45
Save record without changing the date value, becomes: 31/12/2009 00:00:00
```

How to make `<t:inputCalendar>` to retain its original date/time value if there's no value change?

Answer (score 1):

`inputCalender` is meant for dates without time. Use `inputDate` if the time is important.